# Jquery printing out a string reorganizes website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched on google but didn't find answer.

Here is jsfiddle so you can see it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ohk6ho8a/

When you type text into the line and submit 1 div moves under another.
Any idea how to fix this?

HTML file: - other files at jsFiddle (it's pain to copy paste code here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Game</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gameScript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>
    <p id="help" style="display:none;">This is help</p>
<div id="divWrapper">
<div id="console">
<div id="placeholder"></div>
</div>
<div id="menu">

<div id="placeholder2"></div>
</div>
</div>

<form onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off">
    <center><input type="text" id="command_line" autofocus="autofocus" size="50"></input><center>
    <center><input type="submit" id="submit" size="50" ></input><center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen?

Comment: if you type help just prin "this is help" and if anything else then just print what you typed. For now it isnt supposed to make sense I need to set up the console and it is reorganizing every time you type something in :/

Answer (score 0):

On your #console and #menu remove inline-block and change them both to float:left;

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ohk6ho8a/1/

```
float:left;
```

instead of

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should float the two divs (float: left for both) and apply a clearfix style on the parent.